# Accessing memory below the stack on linux

Tags: c, linux, callstack

This program accesses memory below the stack.

I would assume to get a segfault or just `nul`s when going out of stack bounds but I see actual data. (This is assuming 100kb below stack pointer is beyond the stack bounds)

Or is the system actually letting me see memory below the stack? Weren't there supposed to be kernel level protections against this, or does that only apply to allocated memory?

**Edit:** With `1024*127` below char pointer it randomly segfaults or runs, so the stack doesn't seem to be a fixed 8MB, and there seems to be a bit of random to it too.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  char * x;
  int a;
  for( x = (char *)&x-1024*127; x<(char *)(&x+1); x++){
    a = *x & 0xFF;
    printf("%p = 0x%02x\n",x,a);
  }
}
```

**Edit:** Another wierd thing. The first program segfaults at only `1024*127` but if I printf downwards away from the stack I don't get a segfault and all the memory seems to be empty (All `0x00`):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  char * x;
  int a;
  for( x = (char *)(&x); x>(char *)&x-1024*1024; x--){
    a = *x & 0xFF;
    printf("%p = 0x%02x\n",x,a);
  }
}
```

Comment: 100kb below the stack pointer is probably not off the stack as the stack is about 8MB long and grows downwards on x86.

Comment: Use `cat /proc/$PID/maps` to understand where is your stack

Comment: 19..98, when I use `1000*127` it segfaults on and off, seemingly at random

Comment: Yes, randomly, because even the stack is concerned about [ASLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASLR)

Comment: Pedantic sad point. :-) In theory the above program could legally come up with all kinds of results, as I'm not aware of anything that compels the compiler to place the object x at any particular location, it doesn't even have to be on the stack, but of course practically speaking that's the kind of strategy that is typical. Not that I can claim to be an expert on the standards docs. :-) So the results depend entirely on accidental compiler-specifics. To get the stack pointer value reliably you would have to write a little asm (maybe inline asm).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you access memory, you're accessing the process address space.

The process address space is divided into pages (typically 4 KB on x86). These are *virtual* pages: their contents are held elsewhere.  The kernel manages a mapping from virtual pages to their contents.  Contents can be provided by:

- A physical page, for pages that are currently backed by physical RAM. Accesses to these happen directly (via the memory management hardware).
- A page that's been swapped out to disk. Accessing this will cause a page fault, which the kernel handles. It needs to fill a physical page with the on-disk contents, so it finds a free physical page (perhaps swapping that page's contents out to disk), reads in the contents from disk, and updates the mapping to state that "virtual page X is in physical page Y".
- A file (i.e. a memory mapped file).
- Hardware devices (i.e. hardware device registers). These don't usually concern us in user space.

Suppose that we have a 4 GB virtual address space, split into 4 KB pages, giving us 1048576 virtual pages. Some of these will be mapped by the kernel; others will not. When the process starts (i.e. when main() is invoked), the virtual address space will contain, amongst other things:

- Program code. These pages are usually readable and executable.
- Program data (i.e. for initialised variables). This usually has some read-only pages and some read-write pages.
- Code and data from libraries that the program depends on.
- Some pages for the stack.

These things are all mapped as pages in the 4 GB address space. You can see what's mapped by looking at /proc/(pid)/maps, as one of the comments has pointed out. The precise contents and location of these pages depend on (a) the program in question, and (b) address space layout randomisation (ASLR), which makes locations of things harder to guess, thereby making certain security exploitation techniques more difficult.

You can access any particular location in memory by defining a pointer and dereferencing it:

```
*(unsigned char *)0x12345678
```

If this happens to point to a mapped page, and that page is readable, then the access will succeed and yield whatever's mapped at that address. If not, then you'll receive a SIGSEGV from the kernel. You could handle that (which is useful in some cases, such as JIT compilers), but normally you don't, and the process will be terminated. As noted above, due to ASLR, if you do this in a program and run the program several times then you'll get non-deterministic results for some addresses.

Comment: This answers the original question in great details so I'll mark it. I'll make a new one for my new question

Answer (score 1):

There is usually quite a bit of accessible memory below the stack pointer, because that memory is used when you grow the stack normally. The stack itself is only controlled by the value of the stack pointer - it is a software entity, not a hardware entity.

However, system code may assume typical stack usage. I. e., on some systems, the stack is used to store state for a context switch, while a signal handler runs, etc. This also depends on whether the hardware automatically switches stack pointers when leaving user mode. If the system does use your stack for this, it will clobber the data you stored there, and that can really happen at every point in your program.

So it is not safe to manipulate stack memory below the stack pointer. It's not even safe to assume that a value that has successfully been written will still be the same in the next line code. Only the portion above the stack pointer is guaranteed not to be touched by the runtime/kernel.

---

It goes without saying, that this code invokes undefined behavior. The pointer arithmetic is invalid, because the address `&x-1024*127` is not allocated to the variable `x`, so that dereferencing this pointer invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: How is `&x-1024*127` invalid? Unless the base pointer changes it will always be the same location right? I'm honestly more curious why the second example doesn't segfault now

Comment: Luck. Pure luck. You didn't go far enough down to get out of the memory you are permitted access to. Whether you should have been _trying_ to access it is a separate matter.

Answer (score 1):

> This is undefined behavior in C. You're accessing a random memory address which, depending on the platform, may or may not be on the stack. It may or may not be in memory this user can access; if not you will get a segfault or similar. There are absolutely no promises either way.

Actually, it's not undefined behaviour, it's pretty well defined. Accessing memory locations through pointers is and was always defined since C is as close to the hardware as it can be.
I however agree that accessing hardware through pointers when you don't know exactly what you're doing is a dangerous thing to do.

> Don't Do That. (If you're one of the five or six people who has a legitimate reason to do this, you already know it and don't need our advice.)

It would be a poor world with only five or six people legitimately programming operating systems, embedded devices and drivers (although it sometimes appears as if the latter is the case...).

Comment: Even in those, this is almost always the Wrong Way to solve the problem. I stand by my "five or six"

Comment: The previous poster is missing the point. It's not about the use of pointers. The point is that compilers are free to allocate objects wherever they want to within certain constraints, as long as the program behaves 'as if' it were equivalent to something prescribed by the standards. You are just guessing (reasonably) that a particular compiler will choose to allocate that object at some particular place and that that place will be on the stack, not a static.

Comment: On many ancient processors + operating systems values below the stack pointer are in constant danger of being wiped out by saved info pushed onto the stack when the next interrupt happens - unless it is the kind of architecture + kind of interrupt that involves a switch onto a separate stack. This causes one-in-a-million random bugs if values below the SP are used for a really short period of time only, as you normally get away with it since the probability of a doomful interrupt trashing your illegal location within a tiny time window is incredibly small. Only seen it once.

Answer (score 0):

This is undefined behavior in C. You're accessing a random memory address which, depending on the platform, may or may not be on the stack. It may or may not be in memory this user can access; if not you will get a segfault or similar. There are absolutely no promises either way.

Don't Do That. (If you're one of the five or six people who has a legitimate reason to do this, you already know it and don't need our advice.)